# Drawing histogram or column not based on zero line

Tags: pine-script

Is there any way in pine script to draw a histogram or column not based on zero line?

I need to plot 5 different histograms on single indicator but I don't see any way possible to do that because they will overflow eachother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a plot with style set to `plot.style_columns` or `plot.style_histogram`, you can use an additional argument `histbase` to specify the reference level for the columns/histogram. Here's how it could look:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
plot(rsi(close, 14), style=plot.style_columns, histbase=50)
```

If you have several plots that don't overlap in values, you can add a custom `histbase` to each of them and have several sets of columns/histograms in the same pane.